# Assigning values as concatenation of 2 columns from another table during INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am now working on a mySQL database and I need to create a table of users with a key of format like this: `{CompanyID}{auto-increment-ID}` for example : CORP1 / COM1.

I now have a "company" table with the CompanyID and the auto-increment counts (implemented with triggers). The user records contain the CompanyID. Is there any ways I can generate the above key while inserting the record into the user table (or automatically right after inserting)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why even insert it? Why not query the concatination (or create a view that does so) when you need it?

Comment: ohhhhh how come i overlooked this! thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, syntax :

```
CONCAT (string1, string2,…)
```

maybe something like this :

```
INSERT INTO your_table (your_column) VALUES (CONCAT (company_id, '/', increment_id))
```

From here : [link](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php)